# Convert array of object into another using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq, object

I have this below lines of code.

```
List<ModelsView> ModelsData

ModelsData= (from l1 in data
             select new ModelsView()
             {
                 Id = l1.Id, 
                 Name = l1.Name,
                 Age = l1.Age,
                 AgePlusTen = Age+ 10                                   
             }).OrderBy(i => i.PortiaId).ToList();
```

Her you can see, i am using linq to convert data into ModelsData. I donot have any problem doing so. Only problem arises when i add 'AgePlusTen' field. Here i am doing Age+10 and Age is a field added just before this. It doesnot allow me to do Age+10.

It says Age doesnot exist in the current context. Can anyone please let me know how i can add fields and manipulate them based on earlier added fields

Comment: You should consider making the ``AgePlusTen`` member like this ``public int AgePlusTen { get { return Age + 10; } }`` and remove setting it - but you definetly should re-think the whole ``Age`` thing itself, it is recommended to store a ``DateTime`` and compare it with ``DateTime.Now`` instead of having an ``Age`` that has to be incremented every year. Do I really want to know what the reasoning behind ``AgePlusTen`` ?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler answered your question.  No you can't.

why can't you just use `AgePlusTen = l1.Age+ 10` though?  that should work fine.

Comment: tat is so dumb of me.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ModelsView> ModelsData

ModelsData= (from l1 in data
             let agePlusTen = l1.Age + 10 // add this
             select new ModelsView()
             {
                 Id = l1.Id, 
                 Name = l1.Name,
                 Age = l1.Age,
                 AgePlusTen = agePlusTen // use it here                         
             }).OrderBy(i => i.PortiaId).ToList();
```

`let` allows you to store the result of a sub-expression. It can even be used to define an enumerable type that can itself be queried.

You can find out more about it here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause)

Comment: Oh, I presumed you gave a simplified example ^^ still `let` will come in handy someday. Have fun coding!

Comment: upvoted for `let` which I didn't think of...  (I'm more of a lambda man when it comes to LINQ stuff really)